# Show the existence of a basis for which matrix of a linear transformation is of the given form.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Consider a linear transformation $T:\mathbb{R}^5\to\mathbb{R}^5$ defined by $$T(x)=Kx, $$ where $$K=\begin{pmatrix}-55&34&-21&13&-8\\ 5&-3&2&-1&1\\ 0&1&1&2&3\\ 5&8&13&21&34\\ 55&89&144&233&377 \end{pmatrix}.$$
Show that there exists a basis B of $\mathbb{R}^5$ such that $$[T]_B=\begin{pmatrix}0&0&0&0&0\\ 0&0&0&0&0\\ 0&0&0&0&0\\ 0&0&0&a&b\\ 0&0&0&c&d \end{pmatrix}.$$
My attempt: I have calculated that Rank(T)$=2$ which means that its Nullity is $3$. This means that there exist three linearly independent eigen vectors $\{v_1, v_2, v_3\}$ corresponding to eigen value $0$. How to look for the other two vectors?

Comment: You need them from the range of $T$. Basically you need to prove that $\ker T$ is disjoint from the range.

Comment: I think it might help to look for vectors in the null space of a matrix containing only the first three rows, but not in the null space of the whole matrix